# How to check an entire column of a model for a value in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, models

I would like to check a column of a table in my database using laravel 4 for a certain value.  I haven't seen anything in the documentation describing how to do this.

I assume it's something like:

```
if(Artist::fbid == "546")

endif
```

Where "Artist" is my model, "fbid" is the field i'm interest in (the column), and "546" is the value I am comparing it against.

I do not know the proper way to do this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a magic where method:

```
$artist = Artist::whereFbid(546)->get();
```

Or the standard where method:

```
$artist = Artist::where('fbid', '=', 546)->get();
```

Comment: Can I use this in the context of an if statement?  As in, taking that, and running "if($artist) something; endif

Comment: Well, this belongs in your controller and not your view, but:

    if (Artist::whereFbid(546)->get()->first()) {
        // Do something
    }